# INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already -

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, log4j

Getting this error in catalina.out when i start Tomcat 6.  Any thoughts?

```
Jul 01, 2014 4:42:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory AAA0628
Jul 01, 2014 4:42:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory AAA0701
Jul 01, 2014 4:42:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory AAA0627
Jul 01, 2014 4:42:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory AAA0606
Jul 01, 2014 4:42:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory AAA0629
Jul 01, 2014 4:42:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory AAA0616
Jul 01, 2014 4:42:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Jul 01, 2014 4:42:35 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.log4j.spi.NOPLoggerRepository.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLoggerRepository(LogManager.java:197)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:228)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.isDebugEnabled(Log4JLogger.java:299)
```

Comment: Make sure your app is not being cached by tomcat.

Comment: thanks. how do i check if my app is cached by tomcat?

Comment: Hint: it's not an error, it's INFO :)

Comment: @gerrytan : Where to check if caching is enabled for my app?